# text concatenation PHP

Tags: php, json

having problems using the text concatenation with the '->' operator in PHP.
I cant seem to get the syntax right for `$playerArray[$x] = $players->$p . $x;`

all this code should do is step through the 'Players' JSON object and return the values from players 1 - 15

```
$playerArray = array();
    $p = "Player_";
    for ($x = 0; $x < 15; $x++) {
        $playerArray[$x] = $players->$p . $x;
        // insert into database the above 
    }
```

Here is the json object im trying to get values from.

[image]

Comment: `$players->{$p . $x}`

Comment: @Wrikken Thankyou!, wasted hours on that

Comment: @Wrikken : Post yours as an answer and get it accepted before wrong answers overrun this thread!

Comment: @Dagon I didn't know that existed.  What a great reference!

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to refer to the $players object using array notation, similar to how you would refer to the object in Javascript?

```
$playerArray = array();
    $p = "Player_";
    for ($x = 0; $x < 15; $x++) {
        $playerArray[$x] = $players[$p . $x];
        // insert into database the above 
    }
```